# SharePoint Designer workflow error: The token service returned an error type of 'unauthorized_client' with the following description:

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have created SharePoint designer 2013 workflow on SharePoint Online list.
The site is restored from template.
I am getting following error from workflow.

```
Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled after 9/29/2018 9:55 AM. Details of last request: HTTP  to https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/site/subsite1/subsite2/_api/web/lists(guid'd5a0eced-1456-4f7e-aad0-d327ea860912') Correlation Id:  Instance Id: 955783ad-2f95-487e-a194-73abb943edb6 

System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled. ---> 
System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to fetch an access token from the token service. 
The token service returned an error type of 'unauthorized_client' with the following description: AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 'c13d643f-945a-46c3-8e4f-d3a7a70b6ed0' was not found in the directory ce02dcd7-f1dd-42f4-9dc3-1959d1672bac, Trace ID: 11414f23-e2b5-428e-9b82-945f4ebea401,Correlation ID: d132cb0a-6f47-e015-98a3-fa6aa32f74e0,Timestamp: 2018-09-28 04:30:25Z ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Security.OAuthS2SSecurityTokenServiceCredential.FetchAccessToken(Uri stsUri, String targetServiceAudience, String authenticatorToken, HttpWebRequest request, TimeSpan timeout, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity, TimeSpan& expirationDuration)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Security.OAuthS2SSecurityTokenServiceCredential.FetchAccessToken(Uri stsUri, String targetServiceAudience, String authenticatorToken, HttpWebRequest request, TimeSpan timeout, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity, TimeSpan& expirationDuration)
at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Security.OAuthS2SSecurityTokenServiceCredential.GetAccessTokenFromTokenService(OAuthS2SPrincipal client, OAuthS2SPrincipal targetServiceAudience, HttpWebRequest originalRequest, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity, TimeSpan& expirationDuration)
at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Security.OAuthS2SSecurityTokenServiceCredential.GetAuthorization(OAuthS2SAuthenticationChallenge[] bearerChallenges, HttpWebRequest request, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Security.OAuthS2SAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateInternal(String challenge, WebRequest request, OAuthS2SCredential credential, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Security.OAuthS2SAuthenticationModule.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
at System.Net.AuthenticationManagerDefault.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
at System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e, Boolean& disableUpload)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DoSubmitRequestProcessing(Exception& exception)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(CoreResponseData coreResponseData)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.OnEndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext context, IAsyncResult result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying the update to your SharePoint Designer 2013? Here is the link to download update: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42009
This update is for 64-bit SPD2013.

I hope it may work.

Thanks and regards,
Purushottam